# Symbolic differentiation of a function two variables, one being an array

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function in terms of a scalar variable and an array variable

A simplified version of the function is

```
Fun[x_, y_] = Sum[y[i + 1]*x^i/Factorial[i],{i, 1, cmax}]
```

I want to calculate symbolic differentiation with respect to `x` and `y[i]`. How can I do that in Mathematica? My actual function is more complex than this, but I think the one shown here will suffice to put me on the right track.

I need to calculate Hessian and Jacobian in order to see if the function is convex.

Comment: `Grad[Fun[x,y],Array[y,cmax]]`?

Comment: This works. How about calculating Hessian and Jacobian? I need to see if the function is convex.

Comment: You can also do e.g. `D[ Fun[x,y], y[2] ]`.  Check the docs to see how to take higher derivatives with `D`.

Comment: The Hessian is the `Grad` of the `Grad`. The Jacobian is not defined for functions which do not preserve dimensions. Did you try to look at the docs?

Comment: I did and I can take the single derivative and the second derivate with respect to only x or only Array[y,cmax]. But if I do `Grad[Fun[x,y],{{x,Array[y,cmax]}}]` then I get error `{x,{y[1],y[2],...}}` is not a non-empty list of valid variables.

Comment: Because `{x,{y[1],y[2],...}}` is really not a list of variables. Its first entry is a variable but its second one is a list. You should use `{x,y[1],y[2],...}`, which can be obtained by `Flatten[{x,{y[1],y[2],...}}]`